# Failure when searching for all polygons near a point using mongoose/mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geospatial, geojson

I am trying to search for any GeoJSON polygon that is with x number of kilometers from a point ordered by distance from the point. It's important that it is a GeoJSON polygon and not a GeoJSON point.

I have the following but I get an error:

> 'Unable to execute query: error processing query: ns=geoPolygonExample.areas limit=1000 skip=0\nTree: GEONEAR  field=loc.coordinates maxdist=0.0156961 isNearSphere=1\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query'

I have checked that my index is correct and I have dropped my database in between schema changes but can't figure this out. The code I am running is below and will work on it's own.

```
    /* Schema */
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var AreaSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  loc: {
    type : { type : String, default : 'Polygon' },
    coordinates: []
  }
})
AreaSchema.index({coordinates: '2dsphere'});

mongoose.model('Area', AreaSchema)
var Area = mongoose.model('Area')
/* Mongo connect */

var conn = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/geoPolygonExample')
// Error handler
mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});

/* Test case */
var my_area = new Area({
  "name": "Test",
  "loc": {
    "coordinates": [[
      [ -85.56045071399187, 38.215601 ],
      [ -85.56080428954273, 38.21842155313534 ],
      [ -85.5618514284852, 38.221133713995485 ],
      [ -85.56045071399187, 38.215601 ]
    ]],
    "type" : "Polygon"
  }
});
my_area.save( function (err) {
  Area
  .find({})
  .where('loc.coordinates')
  .near({
    center: [ -85.56045071399187, 38.215601 ],
    maxDistance: 100/6371,
    spherical: true
  })
  .exec(function(err, areas){
    console.log("err: ", err);
    console.log("areas: ", areas);
  //* result: err:  { [MongoError: n/a]
  //* name: 'MongoError',
  //* message: 'n/a',
  //* '$err': 'Unable to execute query: error processing query: ns=geoPolygonExample.areas limit=1000 skip=0\nTree: GEONEAR  field=loc.coordinates maxdist=0.0156961 isNearSphere=0\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query',
  //* code: 17007 }
  //* areas:  undefined
  });

})
```

Comment: I have also checked with a GeoJSON linter so I am confident in my GeoJSON being accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `2dshpere` index should be created on the `loc` property, not the `coordinates` property. Try changing your index statement to:

```
AreaSchema.index({loc: '2dsphere'});
```

Also, indexes are created in the background, sometimes taking a while to be generated, depending on the amount of existing data in the collection. Since your `insert` and `find` commands are running immediately after the model is registered you may receive an error the first time you run this code, since the index will most likely not exist yet.

Comment: Wow, that ended up being the problem. Much appreciated.